# Django 1.10 - How can babel.js access static files?

Tags: django, babeljs, django-staticfiles

I have `babeljs` installed in my project. In [docs](https://bitbucket.org/rsalmaso/django-babeljs) this is how to compile javascript files:

> load file.js, try to transpile it with babeljs and copy the result
>   into the template (acts the same as the include tag) {% babel
>   "file.js" %}

It works amazing, but I can include only files from my template directory.

**Problem**:

How to include static files, which are not stored inside template directory?

Comment: did you add babeljs in your installed app.. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-babeljs/0.1

Comment: yes, sure. It works when i try to babelize javascript file located in templates folder. But I dont know how to babelize javascript file located in static files folder.